# How to concatenate strings faster in c++?

Tags: c++, string, append, concatenation

In my code I am decoding an input and have to append each decoded part to an output string.
Like 
  `output_string+= "127=" + decoded_ans;`
This will happen roughly 200 times. I feel the above method is not fast as it is constantly assigning more memory and what not. I know that the output_string will not go above 5000 characters. Is there a better(faster) way to this using maybe char arrays or something?
Time is very important to my code.

Comment: You can .reserve() your string if you know how long it will be

Comment: Or use a `std::stringstream`, which will help you avoid intermediary string objects like in your question.

Comment: I tried both. std::stringstream gives better results than the .reserve(). Not sure why though